# How do I invert the rows in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have 1 column, for example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want the column to become

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Obviously, the columns are not as straightforward as this, though it should be the same.

PS: I can't make columns in this forum. It shows as a row.

Comment: Take a look how to do it by using a help column: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hub/2010/05/06/excelling-in-excel-how-to-flip-a-column-of-data/

Answer (score 2):

Just click on any cell in a column and this little macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FlipColumn()
   Dim cl As Long, N As Long, i As Long
   cl = ActiveCell.Column
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, cl).End(xlUp).Row
   ReDim ary(1 To N) As Variant

   For i = 1 To N
      ary(i) = Cells(i, cl).Value
   Next i

   For i = 1 To N
      Cells(i, cl).Value = ary(N - i + 1)
   Next i
End Sub
```

will invert the column contents.

It does not rely on the "sorted" nature of the original order.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the data then sort `Highest to lowest`.

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why this has a downvote, seems to me to be a valid answer to the question..

Comment: @Raystafarian though it wasn't me, I would think it's because it doesn't answer the question. The OP stated that his data is more complicated, which implies that it's not sequential. This answer only works for OPs (bad) example. If you were to say, add a helper column with `=ROW()`, paste values and THEN apply this technique then it would work.

Comment: @Kyle this would work on any descending series, regardless of how far between items. It also works on mixed fields. Given the lack of clarity in the question, I wouldn't have posted this, but I can't say it's wrong.

Comment: @Kyle Actually, the OP wrote "*columns are not as straightforward as this*". How you were able to ascertain the details of it not being sequential is beyond me. Regardless, we cannot assume anything. What if this is really what the OP is asking for? Do we not answer because we assume they want something else. Unless the OP clarifies, it does answer the question.

Comment: @Raystafarian I worded that wrong, I meant "unsorted", instead of "not sequential," that's my bad. Agreed on the lack of clarity though, maybe I shouldn't try to mind read.

Comment: If you're going to assume that the numbers in the example are anything more than placeholders to illustrate the desired before & after sequence, then your answer is way more complicated than it needs to be. You could just enter 5 and 4, and then drag down to autofill, which would also be a valid answer. I didn't downvote, but the question implies that you can't make assumptions about that actual values.  It isn't necessary, anyway, because it's just as easy to make a general solution that handles any data.  Just expand your example so that you're describing a helper column instead of the data.